# Helper renderer inside if statements

Tags: meteor

Refer to the following code:

```
  Template.EditProfile.helpers({
    'welcomeMessage': function() {
      if (Session.get("welcomeMessage")) {
        var welcomeMessage = Session.get("welcomeMessage");
        delete Session.keys['welcomeMessage']
        return welcomeMessage;
      } else {
        return false;  
      }
    }
  })
```

In html,

```
    {{#if welcomeMessage}}
      <div class="change-explain red-msg">{{ welcomeMessage }}</div>
    {{else}}
      <div class="change-explain">People will see your username on your comments.</div>
    {{/if}}
```

This always renders nothing. If I take that outside if statements, it works fine. What am I missing here about reactive style?

Answer (score 2):

In Meteor the Session variable itself is reactive, meaning that when you change the value of the "welcomeMessage" session variable, your "welcomeMessage" helper will run again and not display anything. To give it a test, comment out the `delete Session.keys['welcomeMessage']` and while your app is running, set the session manually in the console by typing something like `Session.set('welcomeMessage', "test")` and then `Session.set('welcomeMessage')`

If you wanted to set the class based off that session variable you could add a helper like:

```
'getClass': function() {
    var className = "";
    if (Session.get("welcomeMessage"))
        className = 'red-msg';
    return className;
}
```

and a message helper like:

```
'getMessage': function() {
    var messsage = "People will see your username on your comments.";
     if (Session.get("welcomeMessage"))
         messsage = Session.get("welcomeMessage");

        return messsage;
}
```

and then your html would look like:

```
<div class="change-explain {{getClass}}">{{getMessage}}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Then how should I change the code to add a class `red-msg` only when `welcomeMessage` is not undefined?